# Unable to export Apple Push Services certificate in .p12 format

Tags: ios, macos, certificate, push, keychain

When I was working on a project, my MacBook was broken. I did format my Macbook and work with backup files. App ID in the app store has been created from a CSR file of the old MacBook.

Recently, I did download the Apple Push Certificates. and then enrolled this certificate to the keychain. I tried to extract p12 . But could not be extracted p12. When I tried to right click and export the certificate, I was not able to export that as .p12 file as the .p12 file extension was disabled while saving. And It did not appear to "My Certificates" keychain.

I did create a new push notification certificate with a new CSR file. but not working.

I have thoroughly searched for an answer. And I found that who created the App ID with his Macbook can be extracted p12.

I was frustrated. Because my MacBook was formatted. And My app is on sale now with app id that created from a CSR file of the old MacBook.

If I create the new App ID and update the app, 
It confuses a few hundred users. Please help me!

**Configuration**

MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2010) / OS X 10.11.5 / Keychain Access 9.0 / Xcode 7.3.1

---

#### appended in 2016.7.7.

I did try to create new App ID with new CSR file. but could not create new App ID with same Bundle ID.[[screenshot 1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZSb6.png)

And could not remove current App ID.[[screenshot 2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KV0kI.png)

And Apple said, "the Bundle ID cannot be changed if the first version of your app has been approved".

Answer (score 1):

If your app is on app store with previous app id and .p12 file,It will not affect your apple push notification service for already released app.

If you have not backed up your keychain before formatting,you need to create new  CSR file on system first & then create  new APN certificate with new CSR and new distribution certificate ,then create new provisioning profile with new distribution certificate.After upgrading app with new app id & .p12 file,everything will work fine as before.

Comment: I did try to create new App ID with new CSR file. but could not create new App ID with same Bundle ID.[ http://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZSb6.png ]... And could not remove current App ID.[ http://i.stack.imgur.com/KV0kI.png ]

Comment: in developer account  first create new distribution certificate from certificate section .Select your app id then click on  edit & you can see delete option at the bottom to delete that app id.Create new app id & push notification certificate & then create new provisioning profile for your app.

Comment: I did do that but Apple said "The App ID 'XXX' appears to be in use by the App Store, so it can not be removed at this time."

Comment: Oh... Apple said, "the Bundle ID cannot be changed if the first version of your app has been approved". ( http://i.stack.imgur.com/6QWkC.png )

Comment: sorry,Just use your existing app id and change push notification certificate for production with new CSR & then create new provisioning profile with new distribution certificate.

Comment: Thank you... but, I did create a new push notification certificate with a new CSR file. But could not be extracted p12.

Comment: what error you are getting after selecting apn certificate in keychain access

Comment: I did download the Apple Push Certificates. and then enrolled this certificate to the keychain. When I tried to right click and export the certificate, I was not able to export that as .p12 file as the .p12 file extension was disabled while saving.

Comment: Just expand that certificate first & then try to export it,it will show .p12 extension enabled.

Comment: if you are unable to expand your current certificate.,delete previous distribution certificate & apn certificate. import newly created distribution certificate,your can see newly created apn certificate in login->My certificates.

Comment: Yes I did... but still not working. [ http://i.stack.imgur.com/exNmy.png ] And It did not appear to "My Certificates" keychain.

Comment: As I see in screenshot you have shared,Apple wwdrca certificate & APN service certificate shown in same section.Apple wwdrca certificate should appear in System->MyCertificate & APN certificate should appear in login->MyCertificate.If you are unable to view APN certificate in My Certificates you may need to reset keychain.Just check some  posts regarding  repair or reset keychain access in case of certificate not appearing in My Certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Did you backup your keychain? If not then you have lost the private key associated with the push notification.

No issue but you will need to create a new push notification certificate, you don't have to use the original CSR file. Just create a new CSR file and request a new push notification certificate.

You should import the new push notification cer file on the machine that create the CSR with which the certificate was requested.

If it does not show up in the keychain try and search for it and make sure that are in the correct section where the certificate was imported (login, system, etc..)

Comment: Thank you... but, I did create a new push notification certificate with a new CSR file.. and still not working.

Comment: It should, use the search in the kay to find the imported certifcate and private key. This is the only way.

Comment: @rckoenes no, it doesn't work. I am having this issue as well.